# Are these two sentences (from a book) correct?

Tags: grammar

I saw these two sentences from a book called "The Art of Racing In The Rain" (I love it!!) and I don't see any verb inside, could anyone explain what's the grammar behind?

"Peripheral vision, seeing things you’ve never seen before. Kinesthetic sensation, driving by the seat of the pants."

Hope my question is clear enough. Thank you guys in advance:)))

Comment: The "seeing" and "driving" are participles. In the wider context, perhaps the author is listing aspects of the sport. A shopping list too, does not contain verbs.

Comment: Not giving enough of the quote is misquoting. << "Balance, anticipation, patience. These are vital. Peripheral vision, seeing things you've never seen before. Kinesthetic sensation, driving by the seat of the pants.  >> This is an interrupted list. < A, B, C. These are vital. D, E. > I've condensed the list here, so the missing 'ands' become a problem. However, sentence fragments can be quite acceptable, as here.